App crashes with memory allocation error while trying to read from Keychain in Swift
I am encountering a recurring crash in my iOS app that seems to be related to memory allocation when accessing Keychain items. The stack trace indicates issues with memory allocation and object creation during the execution of the readValue method from my KeychainItem module, which is used to fetch and decode values from the Keychain.
I have provided the relevant code snippets for the readValue and save methods below. The error points to the crash occurring at the line where decoding the data retrieved from the Keychain is attempted.
Could someone please help me understand what might be causing this issue and how I could resolve it to prevent the crash?
Any insights, suggestions, or debugging tips would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!
func readValue<T: Codable>(object: T.Type) throws -> T? {

    lock.lock()
    defer { lock.unlock() }


    var query = KeychainItem.keychainQuery(withService: service, key: key, accessGroup: accessGroup)
    query[kSecMatchLimit as String] = kSecMatchLimitOne
    query[kSecReturnAttributes as String] = kCFBooleanTrue
    query[kSecReturnData as String] = kCFBooleanTrue

    var queryResult: AnyObject?
    let status = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &queryResult) {
        SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, $0)
    }

    guard status != errSecItemNotFound else { throw KeychainError.noData }
    guard status == noErr else { throw KeychainError.unhandledError(status: status) }

    guard let existingItem = queryResult as? [String: AnyObject],
        let keychainData = existingItem[kSecValueData as String] as? Data else {
        throw KeychainError.unexpectedData
    }

    if let data = try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(object, from: keychainData) {
        return data
    }

    return String(data: keychainData, encoding: .utf8) as? T
}

func save<T: Codable>(_ object: T) throws {
    let encodedData: Data

    if let obj = object as? String {
        encodedData = obj.data(using: .utf8) ?? Data()
    } else {
        encodedData = try PropertyListEncoder().encode(object)
    }

    do {
        try _ = readValue(object: T.self)

        var attributesToUpdate = [String: AnyObject]()
        attributesToUpdate[kSecValueData as String] = encodedData as AnyObject?

        let query = KeychainItem.keychainQuery(withService: service, key: key, accessGroup: accessGroup)
        let status = SecItemUpdate(query as CFDictionary, attributesToUpdate as CFDictionary)

        guard status == noErr else { throw KeychainError.unhandledError(status: status) }
    } catch KeychainError.noData {
        var newItem = KeychainItem.keychainQuery(withService: service, key: key, accessGroup: accessGroup)
        newItem[kSecValueData as String] = encodedData as AnyObject?

        let status = SecItemAdd(newItem as CFDictionary, nil)

        guard status == noErr else { throw KeychainError.unhandledError(status: status) }
    }
}

What i'm trying to do is retrieving Opaque User ID from keychain using these methods, and it calls the readValue and save functions in KeyChainItem Module
class func latestId() -> String? {
    if let idsDict = try? KeychainItem(key: idsArrayKey).readValue(object: [String: String].self) {
        let sortedKeys = Array(idsDict.keys).sorted(by: <)
        if let lastKey = sortedKeys.last {
            return idsDict[lastKey]
        }
    } else {
        updateID()
    }

    return self.latestId()
}

private class func updateID() {
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    let timestamp = Date().timeIntervalSince1970.description

    // Append dictionaries if possible
    if let idsDict = try? KeychainItem(key: idsArrayKey).readValue(object: [String: String].self) {
        let generalDict = idsDict.merging([timestamp: id]) { (_, new) in new }
        try? KeychainItem(key: idsArrayKey).save(generalDict)
    } else {
        try? KeychainItem(key: idsArrayKey).save([timestamp: id])
    }

    try? KeychainItem(key: idsLastUpdateKey).save(timestamp)

    delegate?.didGenerateOpaqueId(id)
}

This is AppCenter Stack Traces
App Center Stack Trace

I don't see the crash log in your question. Did you forget to include it? A question about a crash is not likely to be useful without information about the crash.

I Just added App Center crash traces @matt

Not very helpful. Can't you copy and paste the crash log as actual text? Are you able to symbolicate it on your machine? Are you able to reproduce it? — There appears to be some sort of recursion on line 71 of OpaqueUserIDService.swift. Which line is that?

You can access the keychain without having to use unsafeMutablePointer https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_in_the_keychain nd AnyObject
